# EntityManager persist after find hangs the application

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I'm persisting some data to a table using *JPA*. Before persisting, I check whether the record exists.

```java
    public boolean save(Student student) {
        //below em is an EntityManager object
        Student record = em.find(Student.class, student.getId());
        if (record != null)
            return false;
        em.persist(student);
        return true;
    }
```

This method hangs on `em.persist(student);` can you please tell me what the wrong I am doing.

Comment: Include the entity code in your question

Answer (score 0):

Try to code as below.

```java
public Student save(Student entry) {
  if (entry.getId() == null) {
    // If you don't have id, it's new, so persist
    em.persist(entry);
  } else {
    // If you have id, it's an update of the existing entry, so merge.
    entry= em.merge(entry);
  }
  return entry;
}
```

---

### UPDATE

Realized just now.

You obviously want to save only new entry, right?
Other words, you don't want to save/update existing entry, do you?

```java
public boolean save(Student student) {
  Student record = em.find(Student.class, student.getId());
  if (record != null)
    return false;
  em.persist(student); // ★ Is it ok, if you pass entry with already set id?
  return true;
}
```

Did you try to set `student.id` to null?

Comment: Isn't there any issues with locks, when I persist() immediate after find(). As my code hangs on the line em.persist()

Comment: I don't know is there any issues with locks or no... Updated the answer.

Comment: yes, I do not want to update. only create new record. and yes, object's Id is already set. but still hang on the persist

Comment: Did you try to set student.id to null? ヾ(๑╹◡╹)ﾉ"